# Another nmap question

Tags: networking, nmap

Okay so I've recently learned how to run an entire network scan using nmap to find all the devices currently connected to the network that you're connected to.  So my next question is can you scan a network that you aren't connected to.  Just for example like your neighbors wifi.  Is that possible to do using nmap?  If not what kind of program could be used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, nmap doesn't do this. nmap is an "active" scanner. It works by sending probes/signals to addresses on the network and analyzing the replies. When you can send signals and receive replies then you are, by definition, connected to that network.

Some scanning methods are "passive" as opposed to "active". Passive scans are ones that don't involve transmitting any signals or probes, but listening only. Search for phrases like "passive network scanner" or "passive wifi scan" to read more.